# Loopback Accesstoken without expiry for mobile app users

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

Is there any mechanism to make the **Access Token** of no expiry in loopback js.

One method is to write custom logic in after remote of login, the logic may be update ttl with a higher integer value. I need to know whether any logic like, -1 to set an access token without expiry?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [official release notes](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/CHANGES.md), a support for access tokens with eternal TTL (value -1) was added in Loopback v2.35.0, v3.1.0.

Besides your proposed solution using hooks, you can also set `ttl` of an `AccessToken` while [logging in](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Logging-in-users.html).

```
User.login({
  email: 'me@domain.com',           // must provide email or "username"
  password: 'secret',               // required by default
  ttl: -1                           // keep the AccessToken alive for eternity
}, function (err, accessToken) {
  console.log(accessToken.id);      // => GOkZRwg... the access token
  console.log(accessToken.ttl);     // => 1209600 time to live
  console.log(accessToken.created); // => 2013-12-20T21:10:20.377Z
  console.log(accessToken.userId);  // => 1
});
```